# Proxy Check in python

Tags: python, http, proxy

I have written a script in python that uses cookies and POST/GET. I also included proxy support in my script. However, when one enters a dead proxy, the script crashes. Is there any way to check if a proxy is dead/alive before running the rest of my script?

Furthermore, I noticed that some proxies don't handle cookies/POST headers properly. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can't you just catch the exception?

Comment: I think catching the exception is not the best way to do it, check the comment I left in dbr answer. Could you give me your opinion? because I am planning to write a proxy checker myself (im just starting with python and this will be my second python script).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest was is to simply catch the IOError exception from urllib:

```
try:
    urllib.urlopen(
        "http://example.com",
        proxies={'http':'http://example.com:8080'}
    )
except IOError:
    print "Connection error! (Check proxy)"
else:
    print "All was fine"
```

Also, from [this blog post - "check status proxy address"](http://love-python.blogspot.com/2008/07/check-status-proxy-address.html) (with some slight improvements):

**for python 2**

```
import urllib2
import socket

def is_bad_proxy(pip):    
    try:
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': pip})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        req=urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com')  # change the URL to test here
        sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
        return e.code
    except Exception, detail:
        print "ERROR:", detail
        return True
    return False

def main():
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(120)

    # two sample proxy IPs
    proxyList = ['125.76.226.9:80', '213.55.87.162:6588']

    for currentProxy in proxyList:
        if is_bad_proxy(currentProxy):
            print "Bad Proxy %s" % (currentProxy)
        else:
            print "%s is working" % (currentProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**for python 3**

```
import urllib.request
import socket
import urllib.error

def is_bad_proxy(pip):    
    try:
        proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': pip})
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        req=urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com')  # change the URL to test here
        sock=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('Error code: ', e.code)
        return e.code
    except Exception as detail:
        print("ERROR:", detail)
        return True
    return False

def main():
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(120)

    # two sample proxy IPs
    proxyList = ['125.76.226.9:80', '25.176.126.9:80']

    for currentProxy in proxyList:
        if is_bad_proxy(currentProxy):
            print("Bad Proxy %s" % (currentProxy))
        else:
            print("%s is working" % (currentProxy))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Remember this could double the time the script takes, if the proxy is down (as you will have to wait for two connection-timeouts).. Unless you specifically have to know the proxy is at fault, handling the IOError is far cleaner, simpler and quicker..

Comment: But some proxies can connect to the url but they don't open the actual html from that url, they show a custom error so you can't catch an exception there, wouldn't be better to check for a string in req.read()?

Comment: What's the difference between `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` and the `urllib` parameter `timeout`?

Comment: @macdonjo pretty sure the urllib timeout parameter is new in Python 3. It's probably much better than the `socket.setdefaulttimeout` which applies globally

Comment: checking an invalid proxy with this code seems to take very long time (1 minute ++).

Answer (score 4):

you can use the Proxy-checker library which is as simple as this

```
from proxy_checker import ProxyChecker

checker = ProxyChecker()
checker.check_proxy('<ip>:<port>')
```

output :

```
{
  "country": "United States",
  "country_code": "US",
  "protocols": [
  "socks4",
  "socks5"
  ],
  "anonymity": "Elite",
  "timeout": 1649
}
```

with the possibility of generating your own proxies and check them with two lines of code

Answer (score 4):

you can use ip-getter website to get the IP by which you are sending a request, then check if the IP is the same as your proxy IP or some thing else. Here is a script for that matter:

```
import requests

proxy_ip = "<IP>"
proxy_port = "<PORT>"
proxy_user = "<USERNAME>"
proxy_pass = "<PASSWORD>"

proxies = {
    "http": f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}/",
    "https": f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}/"
}

url = 'https://api.ipify.org'

try:
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    assert response.text==proxy_ip
except:
    print("Proxy does not work")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better approach is like dbr said, handling the exception.

Another solution that could be better in some cases, is to use an external **[online proxy checker](http://proxyipchecker.com/)** tool to check if a proxy server is alive and then continue using your script without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

There is one nice package [Grab](http://docs.grablib.org/)
So, if it ok for you, you can write something like this(simple valid proxy checker-generator):

```
from grab import Grab, GrabError

def get_valid_proxy(proxy_list): #format of items e.g. '128.2.198.188:3124'
    g = Grab()
    for proxy in proxy_list:
        g.setup(proxy=proxy, proxy_type='http', connect_timeout=5, timeout=5)
        try:
            g.go('google.com')
        except GrabError:
            #logging.info("Test error")
            pass
        else:
            yield proxy
```

Comment: The documentation is hardly English

Answer (score 0):

ok, so both solution 1 and 2 individually didn't work for me. But by combining those can work perfectly. So, here is my code which worked-

```
def is_bad_proxy(pip):
  try:
    proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies=pip)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.example.com')  # change the URL to test here
    sock = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
    if 200 <= sock.getcode() < 300:
        return False
    else:
        return True
  except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
    return e.code
  except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print('Error: ', e.reason)
    return True
  except Exception as detail:
    print("ERROR:", detail)
    return True

@convert_kwargs_to_snake_case
async def my_proxy(_, info):
    proxy_ip = "<IP>"
    proxy_port = "<PORT>"
    proxy_user = "<USERNAME>"
    proxy_pass = "<PASSWORD>"

    proxies = {
    "http": f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}/",
    "https": f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}/"
}
    if is_bad_proxy(proxies):
        return "not_working"
    else:
        return "working"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).