# Efficient way of checking proxies in python?

Tags: python, proxy, proxies

I was wondering if anyone knew how to check proxies in an efficient manner without taking too long. I've already found an [old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765305/proxy-check-in-python) from 11 years ago that doesn't exactly give what I'm looking for. The methods that I've currently tried are either deprecated and don't work anymore or are extremely slow. An example of something I've tried is this:

```
def checkProxy(proxy):    
try:
    proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy})
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    req=urllib.request.Request('http://www.google.com')
    sock=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    return False
except Exception as detail:
    return False
return True

with open(prxyfile,"r+")as proxyfile:
    for proxy in proxyfile:
        proxy=proxy.replace("\n","")
        if checkProxy(proxy):
            # proxy is good
        else:
            # proxy is bad
```

This works in theory but is extremely slow.

I'm hoping that anyone may know some libraries or modules that would be good for checking proxies. I would also greatly appreciate it if anyone knew how to check proxies for specific URLs, and not just if they work in general. Any help is appreciated, thank you.