# Python Selenium proxy handling

Tags: python, selenium

im currently using public proxies on selenium but if the proxy is dead the driver will just be blank and it takes forever for my exception to toggle and restart the script
i tried multiple things to detect if the page was blank but nothing worked
like

```
driver.page_source
driver.current_url
driver.title
```

none of them print if the proxy doesn't respond
so is there a quick way for me to detect if the page is fully blank or the url hasn't loaded for x amount of seconds

heres an image of the fully blank page even with page timeout i get the same thing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxQXm.png

Answer (score 0):

Just check your proxy before using them.

you can refer to this link for some codes on proxy checking in python.
[Proxy Check in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/765305/13880223)

Comment: i do check them before using them
i use this to check them
https://openproxy.space/software/proxy-checker
and it doesnt seem to help too much